# Pandas.Series.unique() drops unique values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas series of numbers between 1000000 and 99999999. They are serial numbers, so they often repeat. The purpose of the unique() function is to drop duplicates in a series, however see the code below.

```
>>> 10296765 in data.OriginatorUniqueId
True
>>> 10296765 in data.OriginatorUniqueId.unique()
False
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, is there a reasonable explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: Can you provide an actual [mcve]?

Comment: First one checks against a pandas series' *index* while second one checks against a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a different implementation of the `in` method. The `in` method is really implemented with the `__contains__` methods of the respective objects. For a [pandas `Series` or `DataFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L1837-L1839) that is:

```
def __contains__(self, key) -> bool_t:
    """True if the key is in the info axis"""
    return key in self._info_axis
```

For a Series the *info axis* is the row Index, for a DataFrame the *info axis* is the columns Index, so you are checking whether the value is any of your Index labels, not the values of data in the underlying numpy array.

On the other hand, the [numpy.ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__contains__.html) checks for the values of the array itself (numpy arrays don't have an Index like pandas, so what else would you check?)

```
ndarray.__contains__(key, /)
    Return key in self.
```

---

Here's a concrete example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo'], index=['a'], data=7)
#   foo
#a    7

# DataFrame.__contains__ checks for the column labels
'foo' in df
#True

# Series.__contains__ checks for the Index labels
'a' in df['foo']
# True

# ndarray.__contains__ checks against the data in the array
7 in df.to_numpy()
# True
```